# Deploy Apex Trigger using Metadata API deploy() Method

Tags: trigger, metadata-api, deployment

I'm struggling to deploy Apex trigger using Metadata API from my connected app. I have created package.xml and the two trigger files - one with suffix .trigger and another - triggerName-meta.xml. I was able to convert the ZIP to byte array and pass it to metedata api deploy() method. I have followed the sample java code in the docs and adjust it to C#. The deployResult success is true, but no trigger is available in SF.

Here is my zip structure:

[image]

In the docs says that the trigger files should be in folder `triggers`, but if i create such structure:

```
package.xml
       triggers\
               TrigerName.trigger
               TrigerName.trigger-meta.xml
```

The deployResult says that no package.xml file was found.

And here is the deployResult from my code:

[image]

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

**EDIT: The Solution for my case**

Thanks to gaiser i have resolved my issue. Here's the correct folder structure of the ZIP file:

```
unpackaged\
           package.xml
           triggers\
                   TrigerName.trigger
                   TrigerName.trigger-meta.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your folder structure should look like so (if you are deploying unpackaged stuff)

```
unpackaged\
       package.xml  
       triggers\
               TrigerName.trigger
               TrigerName.trigger-meta.xml
```

Replace folder name "unpackaged" with name of your package if you are deploying packaged components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try what you suggest tommorow.

Comment: Thank you once again! Just a little correction -  the `package.xml` file should be inside `unpackaged` folder. This way i was able to deploy my triggers.

Comment: Hi @vortex thanks for the correction. I have updated the answer.